# CollectionViewSource MVVM Implementation for WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I have implemented small demo of CollectionViewSource for WPF DataGrid in MVVM. I would really appreciate any help to verify the implementation and comment on whether this is the right approach to use CollectionViewSource.

```
public class ViewModel : NotifyProperyChangedBase
{       
    private ObservableCollection<Movie> _movieList;
    public ObservableCollection<Movie> MovieList
    {
        get { return _movieList; }
        set
        {
            if (this.CheckPropertyChanged<ObservableCollection<Movie>>("MovieList", ref _movieList, ref value))
                this.DisplayNameChanged();
        }
    }

    private CollectionView _movieView;
    public CollectionView MovieView
    {
        get { return _movieView; }
        set
        {
            if (this.CheckPropertyChanged<CollectionView>("MovieView", ref _movieView, ref value))
                this.DisplayNameChanged();
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
          MovieView = GetMovieCollectionView(MovieList);
    }

    private void DisplayNameChanged()
    {
        this.FirePropertyChanged("DisplayName");
    }

    public void UpdateDataGrid(string uri)
    {            
        MovieView = GetMovieCollectionView(new ObservableCollection<Movie>(MovieList.Where(mov => uri.Contains(mov.ID.ToString())).ToList<Movie>()));
    }

    public CollectionView GetMovieCollectionView(ObservableCollection<Movie> movList)
    {
        return (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(movList);
    }
```

The XAML View :

```
  <Window.Resources>
     <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MovieCollection" Source="{Binding MovieList}">
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </Window.Resources>
   <DataGrid Name="MyDG" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding MovieView}" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

The Code Behind :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Resources.Add("TagVM", new TagViewModel());
        this.DataContext = this.Resources["TagVM"];
    }

    private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uri = ((Hyperlink)sender).NavigateUri.ToString();
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).UpdateDataGrid(uri);
    }
```

The Hyperlink_Click handler invokes the UpdateDataGrid method of the VM passing it comma seperated movie IDs which are then used to filter the MovieList collection using extension methods.

Comment: Your code is a little bit misleading, please verify class names. ViewModel, TagViewModel.. so we can better understand.

Comment: Oh sorry @HichemC, actually had renamed the class name while posting the question. Forgot to change it in the code behind. Good observation though. Thanks for drawing my attention.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should not create new instances of the observable collection and the collection view. Assign a predicate to the filter property on the collecion view and call Refresh whenever you want to filter the collection.

```
public class ViewModel : NotifyProperyChangedBase
{       
    string uri;

    public ObservableCollection<Movie> MovieList { get; private set; }

    public CollectionView MovieView { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel(MoveList movieList)
    {
        MovieList = movieList;
        MovieView = GetMovieCollectionView(MovieList);
        MovieView.Filter = OnFilterMovie;
    }

    public void UpdateDataGrid(string uri)
    {     
        this.uri = uri;
        MovieView.Refresh();
    }

    bool OnFilterMovie(object item)
    {
        var movie = (Movie)item;
        return uri.Contains(movie.ID.ToString());
    }

    public CollectionView GetMovieCollectionView(ObservableCollection<Movie> movList)
    {
        return (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(movList);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Fazzani/Solutions/blob/master/Tools/NotifyProperyChangedBase.cs

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of instantiating a CollectionViewSource in order to enable multi-filtering in a DataGrid: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442498/Multi-filtered-WPF-DataGrid-with-MVVM

The CollectionViewSource was instantiated in the XAML view but is bound to a collection of objects instantiated in the view model.  The view model then uses the CollectionViewSource to filter the data in the DataGrid.

As to what is the *right* approach to instantiate a CollectionViewSource - that is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip adding resources by doing this directly : `DataContext = new TagViewModel();` and doing your bindings normally. but I highly recommend using Dependency Injection.